# Are the default kernels come with official distributions of Ubuntu the most suitable for them?

Tags: kernel

Recently I realized that Ubuntu can be booted with different kernels, and downloading Official Ubuntu distributions from Ubuntu.com there are usually two kernels installed by default on the system. I realized it is possible to install more kernels. I want to know are the kernels that come with the official distribution the best ones for Ubuntu to function well, or as newer the kernel is it is better to boot the system with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reasons why not to update an Ubuntu version to a newer/older kernel version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119803/reasons-why-not-to-update-an-ubuntu-version-to-a-newer-older-kernel-version) && https://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels && https://askubuntu.com/questions/358835/what-are-the-risks-advantages-of-working-with-a-mainline-kernel